# What statistics module for python supports one way ANOVA with post hoc tests (Tukey, Scheffe or other)?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, ipython, statsmodels

I have tried looking through multiple statistics modules for Python but can't seem to find any that support `one-way ANOVA` post hoc tests.

Comment: `TukeyHSD` is built into R. Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: statsmodels has a `tukeyhsd` function in the sandbox, but I've not tried it.

Comment: I am looking for the same function, I guess I will use RPy, an interface to R which seems to work like a charm!

Comment: See [scikit-posthocs](https://github.com/maximtrp/scikit-posthocs).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

one way ANOVA can be used like

```
from scipy import stats
f_value, p_value = stats.f_oneway(data1, data2, data3, data4, ...)
```

This is one way ANOVA and it returns F value and P value.

There is significant difference If the P value is below your setting.

The Tukey-kramer HSD test can be used like

```
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd
print pairwise_tukeyhsd(Data, Group)
```

This is multicomparison. 
The output is like

```
Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD,FWER=0.05
================================================
group1 group2 meandiff   lower    upper   reject
------------------------------------------------
  0      1    -35.2153 -114.8741 44.4434  False 
  0      2     46.697   -40.4993 133.8932 False 
  0      3    -7.5709    -87.49  72.3482  False 
  1      2    81.9123    5.0289  158.7956  True 
  1      3    27.6444   -40.8751  96.164  False 
  2      3    -54.2679 -131.4209 22.8852  False 
------------------------------------------------
```

Please refer to **[this](http://jpktd.blogspot.jp/2013/03/multiple-comparison-and-tukey-hsd-or_25.html)** site how to set the arguments.

The tukeyhsd of statsmodels doesn't return P value.

So, if you want to know P value, calculate from these outputted value or use R.

Comment: After saving the output into a variable `res`, you can get p-values by applying
`psturng(np.abs(res.meandiffs / res.std_pairs), len(res.groupsunique), res.df_total)`, where `psturng` comes from `from statsmodels.stats.libqsturng import psturng`

Comment: I have added p-values to the table and output attributes using a method similar to that suggested by @JavierdelaRosa. Should be added soon -- see the [pull request](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/5418).

Comment: @ami_GS how do you get it to print the results? When I do it, it just prints"tukeyHSDResults object at 0x0DBEBB10....sorry for basic question...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the library [Pyvttbl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvttbl) returns a ANOVA table including post-hoc tests (i.e., TukeyHSD). In fact, what is neat with Pyvttbl is that you can carry out ANOVA for repeated measures also.

See the doc for Anova1way [here](https://github.com/rogerlew/pyvttbl/blob/master/doc/Anova1way.rst)

Comment: Unfortunately this library is no longer supported.