# Least significant difference (LSD) post hoc-test in ANOVA using Python

Tags: python, anova

Recently I've been learning to use Python to do ANOVA analysis. I have already found [an example of using Tukey's test to do ANOVA](http://hamelg.blogspot.be/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-16_23.html) but I want to use the least significant difference (LSD) method. Does anyone know how to do it or is there an example? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see Fisher's least significant differences test listed in [statsmodel's index](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/genindex.html#F) nor in their [multicomp module](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/stats.html?highlight=statsmodels%20stats%20multicomp#module-statsmodels.stats.multicomp). I would contact their support and ask them, which post hoc tests are implemented. Tbh, I wouldn't consider Python for statistical analysis. If you want to work with stats in the future, there is no competitor to R.

Comment: And I just saw [here, that even Tukey's HSD in statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21177789/8881141) doesn't calculate the p value. Meh.

Comment: any news? did you find the LSD test in python?

Comment: NO solution for this issue.